# ORB Image detection and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

Working code for my image detection script. This is functional code.

I'm loading a number of images into an array, and using two classes to generate the two main components I need for my detection; `Vision` and `WindowCapture`.

`WindowCapture` will grab a cropped section of your primary monitor to run detection on, while any images sitting inside the `avoid` directory will attempt to be found within the screen.

```
import cv2 as cv
import os
import glob
from windowcapture import WindowCapture
from vision import Vision


# Change the working directory to the folder this script is in.
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\coyle\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\avoidShipActual')

avoid = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\coyle\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\avoidShipActual\defeat\*.png")

def loadImages(directory):
    # Intialise empty array
    image_list = []
    # Add images to array
    for i in directory:
        img = cv.imread(i, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        image_list.append((img, i))
    return image_list

# initialize the WindowCapture class
wincap = WindowCapture()

def keypoint_detection(image_list):

    for i in image_list:
        needle_img = i[0]
        needle_name = i[1]
        sliced_name = needle_name.split("\\")[-1]

        # load image to find
        objectToFind = Vision(needle_img)
        # get an updated image of the screen
        keypoint_haystack = wincap.get_haystack()
        # crop the image
        x, w, y, h = [600,700,20,50]
        keypoint_haystack = keypoint_haystack[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        kp1, kp2, matches, match_points = objectToFind.match_keypoints(keypoint_haystack, sliced_name)
        match_image = cv.drawMatches(objectToFind.needle_img, kp1, keypoint_haystack, kp2, matches, None)

        if match_points:
            # find the center point of all the matched features
            center_point = objectToFind.centeroid(match_points)
            # account for the width of the needle image that appears on the left
            center_point[0] += objectToFind.needle_w
            # drawn the found center point on the output image
            match_image = objectToFind.draw_crosshairs(match_image, [center_point])

            # move somewhere/do something

        # display the processed image
        cv.imshow('Keypoint Search', match_image)

        # press 'q' with the output window focused to exit.
        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
    
while(True):
    ships_to_avoid = loadImages(avoid)
    keypoint_detection(ships_to_avoid)
```

Vision Class:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

class Vision:
# properties
needle_img = None
needle_w = 0
needle_h = 0

# constructor
def __init__(self, needle_img_path):
    self.needle_img = needle_img_path

    # Save the dimensions of the needle image
    self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
    self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]

def draw_crosshairs(self, haystack_img, points):
    # these colors are actually BGR
    marker_color = (255, 0, 255)
    marker_type = cv.MARKER_CROSS

    for (center_x, center_y) in points:
        # draw the center point
        cv.drawMarker(haystack_img, (center_x, center_y), marker_color, marker_type)

    return haystack_img

def match_keypoints(self, original_image, name, patch_size=32):
    min_match_count = 30

    orb = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=patch_size)
    keypoints_needle, descriptors_needle = orb.detectAndCompute(self.needle_img, None)
    orb2 = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=patch_size, nfeatures=2000)
    keypoints_haystack, descriptors_haystack = orb2.detectAndCompute(original_image, None)

    FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
    index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_LSH, table_number=6, key_size=12, multi_probe_level=1)
    search_params = dict(checks=50)

    try:
        flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
        matches = flann.knnMatch(descriptors_needle, descriptors_haystack, k=2)
    except cv.error:
        return None, None, [], [], None

    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []
    points = []

    for pair in matches:
        if len(pair) == 2:
            if pair[0].distance < 0.7*pair[1].distance:
                good.append(pair[0])

    if len(good) > min_match_count:
        print(str(name) + ' - ' + '%03d keypoints matched - %03d' % (len(good), len(keypoints_needle)))
       
        for match in good:
            points.append(keypoints_haystack[match.trainIdx].pt)
    
    return keypoints_needle, keypoints_haystack, good, points

def centeroid(self, point_list):
    point_list = np.asarray(point_list, dtype=np.int32)
    length = point_list.shape[0]
    sum_x = np.sum(point_list[:, 0])
    sum_y = np.sum(point_list[:, 1])
    return [np.floor_divide(sum_x, length), np.floor_divide(sum_y, length)]
```

WindowCapture Class:

```
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con

class WindowCapture:

# properties
w = 0
h = 0
hwnd = None
cropped_x = 0
cropped_y = 0
offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0

# constructor
def __init__(self, window_name=None):
    # find the handle for the window we want to capture.
    # if no window name is given, capture the entire screen
    if window_name is None:
        self.hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    else:
        self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
        if not self.hwnd:
            raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

    # get the window size
    window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
    self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
    self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

    # account for the window border and titlebar and cut them off
    border_pixels = 0
    titlebar_pixels = 0
    self.w = self.w - (border_pixels * 2)
    self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
    self.cropped_x = border_pixels
    self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

    # set the cropped coordinates offset so we can translate screenshot
    # images into actual screen positions
    self.offset_x = window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
    self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

def get_haystack(self):

    # get the window image data
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
    # dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
    signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

    # free resources
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
    img = img[...,:3]
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

    return img

@staticmethod
def list_window_names():
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

# translate a pixel position on a screenshot image to a pixel position on the screen.
# pos = (x, y)
def get_screen_position(self, pos):
    return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y)
```